# in puzzle game purpose one drawable image crops in to nine number of pieces how can implemented in android

Tags: android

I am developing a puzzle game.  This application I am using one drawable image (r.drawable.image1).  This drawable image crop in to nine number of pieces.  It will display in random order 
How can its implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

crop the nine pieces of original image its dynamically

Comment: hey how did you crop the images into pieces